# Detect the direction of the movement and distance moved by the sensor tag CC2650 STK in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

This is the characteristic data received over Bluetooth (BLE) from **invensense MPU-9250 sensor** used in **sensor tag CC2650STK**.

Initial values
[138,255,185,0,164,0,84,2,160,0,108,64,50,2,101,253,28,252]

Final values
[120,255,122,0,203,0,152,2,216,0,112,64,27,29,253,44,247]

this how data is arranged.
GXLSB:GXMSB:GYLSB:GYMSB:GZLSB:GZMSB, AXLSB:AXMSB:AYLSB:AYMSB:AZLSB:AZMSB

Gyroscope Data:

- GXLSB: Least Significant Byte for X-axis gyroscope reading.
- GXMSB: Most Significant Byte for X-axis gyroscope reading.
- GYLSB: Least Significant Byte for Y-axis gyroscope reading.
- GYMSB: Most Significant Byte for Y-axis gyroscope reading.
- GZLSB: Least Significant Byte for Z-axis gyroscope reading.
- GZMSB: Most Significant Byte for Z-axis gyroscope reading.

Accelerometer Data:

- AXLSB: Least Significant Byte for X-axis accelerometer reading.
- AXMSB: Most Significant Byte for X-axis accelerometer reading.
- AYLSB: Least Significant Byte for Y-axis accelerometer reading.
- AYMSB: Most Significant Byte for Y-axis accelerometer reading.
- AZLSB: Least Significant Byte for Z-axis accelerometer reading.
- AZMSB: Most Significant Byte for Z-axis accelerometer reading.

how to detect the direction of the movement and how much it is moved in dart.